# MultipleOutputFormat support for with 'Job'

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to use MultipleOutputFormat with hadoop 0.20.1 and it seems they only work with deprecated 'JobConf' which in turn uses deprecated Mapper and Reducer (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer) etc., . Any ideas how to to acheive multiple output functionality (or at least naming reducer output functionality) with new 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to rewrite your own, or get it from the actual branch of 0.22.0. I'm not really sure if there is a "new api"- MultipleOutputFormat in 0.21.0 but you could have a look and maybe you're lucky ;)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. 0.21 seems to support MultipleOutputs(Context) which helps my needs.